# Is there a faster way to copy time machine files from one disk to another?

Tags: time-machine, copy-paste

I'm trying to move my time machine backup files all under Backups.backupdb to another drive. I initiated a file copy overnight (b/c I saw that it took OSX forever to prepare for the copy...it basically was counting the files for hours). In the morning I saw that only certain backups(folders with dates) got copied over. I then tried to copy over the ones that didn't get copied...but the OS wouldn't allow me to do that. I got and error that "The operation can’t be completed because backup items can’t be modified." So my plan is to delete the incomplete copy on the new drive and then try to copy over the Backups.backupdb folder again.

Pretty frustrating. Is there a faster way to copy these files via a terminal command so that it doesn't perform all of that file counting prep?

I probably can tar up the entire folder and then do a copy, but will that interfere with any of the file permissions, etc.? The one thing with this approach is that I don't have any more space on my source volume for the tar.

**UPDATE**

I've tried some of the methods that people have suggested below, specifically using Disk Utility's restore function and it's giving me some error messages and unexpected results (at least to me).
I've tried to do the restore two ways:

- With "Erase Destination" checked : Each time (I've tried twice), when the restore has finished I see a message "Could not restore - Invalid Operation" and "Could not restore - Invalid Argument". However, my destination disk does get a copy of my TM files. The weird thing is that my destination disk is EXACTLY like my source disk...even the size. My destination disk is actually 1 TB but after the restore, it shows as 200 GB when I get info from the finder. But in Disk Utility, it shows a 1 TB partition!

I then tried to verify/repair the disk and got:

```
    Invalid B-tree node size
    Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
    Invalid B-tree node size
    Volume repair complete.
    Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
    Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.
```

Don't know if I'm even suppose to verify/repair a TM disk...

- With "Erase Destination" UNchecked : The restore never starts and I get:

```
    Could not restore - Operation not permitted
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to get data off Time Capsule and onto an external drive?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30225/whats-the-fastest-way-to-get-data-off-time-capsule-and-onto-an-external-drive)

Comment: I think this stands well - the other question addresses the IO load of copying the hard links but is wrapped up in time capsule's network and enclosure so it's a special case of the general problem asked here.

Comment: If you can upgrade to MacOS 10.13.4+ the bug that prevented aliases/hard links from copying over in Finder has been fixed. I tried it myself to copy a backup Time Machine disk to another one and it worked perfectly (and it was pretty fast too). More info here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323691/261070.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A normal copy (or copy via rsync or ditto) will not replicate a Time Machine fully as it will convert two directories linked together (as occurs in successive TM backups with no change between) into two separate directories.

The best way is to copy the whole the disk using Disk Utility or the block copy part of [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/cloning-a-time-machine-backup) and probably similar on [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html).

Comment: From the ditto man page: "ditto preserves file hard links (but not directory hard links) present in the source directories" so no help here. It's either Disk Utility or a tool like SuperDuper or CCC.

Comment: @patrix Thanks - the web man page says nothing on that -  CCC uses ditto or rsync for copying so will only do this if it does a block copy http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/cloning-a-time-machine-backup

Comment: My Source disk only contains the Time Machine backup. My Destination disk contains other files. I don't want a clone of my Source disk. I just want to copy the Time Machine files to the Destination disk.

Comment: Due to the use of hard links there is no easy (unix level) way of exactly duplicating a TM backup without significantly increasing the needed disk space. If you just want to store the latest backup on another drive I would recommend to `rsync` (or `ditto`) the `latest` folder in `Backups.backupdb`.

Comment: After looking at Disk Utility again as per @Mark. I've basically decided to move the files that are currently on my Destination drive to another drive. Now I'm basically using Disk Utility's Restore function to erase the contents of my Destination drive and replace it with the contents of my Source drive.

Comment: I'm running into a problem using Disk Utility's Restore function for this. Tried may times and keep getting "Could not restore - Operation not permitted". http://njmac.blogspot.com/2008/11/move-time-machine-backups-to-new-volume.html seems to suggest that SuperDuper is the only one that really works for copying Time Machine backups from one drive to another. Will be giving this a try next.

Comment: Can I use SuperDuper to copy over the TM files to my destination drive without it repartitioning the drive to a smaller partition? The whole point is to move my TM files to a drive that has more space for future backups.

Comment: After many attempts to copy my TM files to a new disk, Disk Utility and Carbon Copy Cloner both DID NOT do the trick. SuperDuper did it perfectly on the first run and didn't reduce the size of my destination partition!

Comment: Another vote for SuperDuper! here.  v3.2.4 successfully copied a big Time Machine backup folder to a new disk, under macOS 10.14.2 Mojave, without it taking any more space.  (Which Finder could *not* do…)  Time Machine happily continues using the new disk as if it were the old one.

Comment: I used SuperDuper 3.2.5 (Dec 2020) (the latest version 3.3.1 fails because it has problems setting permissions to be applied). For the free version, you have to click on Options, then in "During copy" select Erase etc..(default settings are not free)

I copied a 4TB disc that was almost entirely filled with Time Machine backups in just under 34 hours. So about 117GB per hour. (SuperDuper reports 32 MB/s). The new disk had 4.03TB compared with the old disk 3.98TB - no idea why it expanded slightly.

SuperDuper's big advantage you can see the progress. Unfortunately you can’t pause the copy.

Answer (score 8):

Migrating a full 3TB Time Machine encrypted drive to a new 8TB one on macOS 10.14, I ran into all sorts of issues. Trying to do a restore in Disk Utility errored out with “unable to validate source” or “Operation not permitted.” Trying some other suggestions in this post and others, I was able to get exciting new error messages like “Catalog file on image/volume is too badly fragmented,” but no copy.

What worked in the end, at the terminal:

1. Erase the new disk with Disk Utility, matching the format of the source drive: MacOS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)
2. Use `diskutil cs list` in the terminal to get the exact byte size of the Logical Volume on the old drive, and the GUID of the new Logical Volume, as well as the disk numbers for both, e.g., `disk4`.
3. Use the exact byte size from step2 as the size of the new volume. In my case with a 3TB drive it was 2,999,772,905,472 bytes:

   ```
   sudo diskutil cs resizeVolume $new_lv_guid 2999772905472
   ```
4. Using the `pv` command from homebrew, do a low-level block copy of the disks. This is a lot like using `dd`, except you get a progress meter with ETA.

   You need to get the disk numbers from the `diskutil cs list` output. Be careful. **It’s very easy to accidentally overwrite your full backup drive with the new blank one here.**

   ```
   sudo sh -c "$(which pv) --buffer-size 50M -s 2999772905472 < /dev/rdisk${source} > /dev/rdisk${target}"
   ```

   If you get a permission denied / operation not permitted error here, go into Security & Privacy Preferences and add Full-Disk Access for Terminal.app.

   For me this took about 10 hours—I let it run overnight—but, with `pv`, at least you get a progress meter with an ETA.
5. Now, expand the volume to take up all remaining space on the drive:

   ```
   sudo diskutil cs resizeVolume $new_lv_guid 0
   ```

   This took ~ 3 hours for me, with about 5 years of backups. Most of that time was spent by macOS `fsck`ing.

Now you can enjoy your new, more spacious Time Machine drive. You can repurpose the old one, or stow it somewhere safe in case something happens to the new drive.

---

The resizing steps seem to be important; skipping them resulted in a 10-hour file copy that yielded an 8TB volume containing a 3TB filesystem that I couldn’t figure out how to resize.

---

**UPDATE** One potential downside to this approach is that because it’s a bit-for-bit copy, the identifiers are the same between the old disk and the new disk. If I connect the old full disk, Time Machine thinks it’s the new disk, tries to back up, and starts deleting old backups to make room for new ones. It seems like a fine approach for moving data to a larger disk where the older smaller disk will then be wiped.

Comment: Hello Andrew! Thanks for taking the time to type out this step-by-step guide (and I'm hoping to use it to transfer my 1TB backup to a 4TB disk, which up until now hasn't been successful because Finder-copied folders & files take up so much more space on the new disk than the original one). My question to you is:  can I do these steps *without* `cs` a.k.a. corestorage enabled? Enabling core storage appears to be [a potentially unnecessary PITA](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7977508), but it may be necessary because of the guid step 3.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Core Storage is necessary for FileVault which is extremely highly recommended for backup drives, in order to protect your privacy in cases of loss, theft, or improper disposal.

Comment: I'd like to add that I was not able to copy with the mentioned method. The reason was that the system prompted that this "operation is not permitted". After a brief search I've found out that I need to turn off all SIP functionalities. This can be done by restarting macOS by holding command + R and open a terminal.
Here you need to disable by typing "csrutil disable". With the next restart I was able to copy the TM backup

Comment: @andrew my version is 10.14.6 and I completely understand the risk you've mentioned. However I was not able to dd or pv my TimeMachine - backup without turning SIP off. If there is another way I'd happy to hear.

Comment: I keep getting "pv: write failed: Input/output error" at 99% (after 30 hours, 3 attempts - so really 90 hours).  Disks are unmounted. SIP functions are disabled.  Googling the error is not coming up with anything.   Similar to the original situation (3TB -> 8TB). `sudo sh -c "$(which pv) --buffer-size 50M -s 3000249008128 < /dev/rdisk3 > /dev/rdisk5"` - the 8tb was previously successfully resized `Resized Core Storage Logical Volume to 3,000,249,008,128 bytes`

Comment: Despite the error message, does the target disk actually mount afterwards when you disconnect it and reconnect it? It’s possible that that’s normal.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use terminal:

```
cp -RnpP Backups.backupdb
```

- `-R` recursive
- `-n` do not overwrite (if existing copy remnants remain from previous attempt)
- `-p` preserve ACL's, permissions, creation/mod dates, etc.
- `-P` preserve hard links, do not follow any hard or symlinks.

Comment: This is not true. Read `man cp` for macOS. The regular `cp` command shipped with macOS **does not** copy hard links with -P. The man page actually says "Note that cp copies hard-linked files as separate files.  If you need to preserve hard links, consider using tar(1), cpio(1), or pax(1) instead."

Answer (score 1):

Following the [+1 comment about Super Duper!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35149/is-there-a-faster-way-to-copy-time-machine-files-from-one-disk-to-another/376626#comment459329_35183), here are the specs (they did not fit in a comment):

> 12.250.329 files evaluated, 10.408.594 files copied. Effective copy speed 8,68 MB/s.

for cloning a magnetic 2TB Backup drive with several years of backups this year (2019).

This took 63h in total (the info screen would reset its clock every 24 hours, so it showed 15:04:43 in the end) as opposed to a Finder copy which I cancelled after roughly 4 days and a quarter of the files.

Obviously the magnetic disk was not the reason for this taking so long. The reason Finder copies stall on long running backup disks is the sheer number of cascading symbolic links on unchanged files, especially for many small files like Git indices.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Tried the old drag & drop of my TM backup from my old external drive to a new one. Almost three hours later the file count was well over 1,000,000 and it was still ‘preparing’ to move them.

Here’s what I did, and it took less than a hour!

1. Restart Mac in Recovery Mode & choose Disk Utility
2. Select the new drive in Disk Utility’s sidebar
3. Click the Restore button (or go to Edit > Restore)
4. In the Restore drop-down choose the drive you want to clone/move
5. Click Restore
6. Once cloned, wait for Disk Utility to say it’s complete & click Done.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

rsync is a great utility for stuff like this.  I generally use it for stuff like this.  In this case I might use the -aP flags.  I think part of -a ("archive") is also to preserve permissions, ACLs and the like, but I'm not sure.

IIRC, there's also a --delete option that allows you to delete the source file once it has been successfully copied to the destination.  I'd be wary of using that though - usually I do a complete mirror without the --delete option, then I'll re-run the command with the -c and --delete options.  -c is checksum, so it checks all the files you've downloaded against all those on the source via checksum, then deletes the source if there's a match, otherwise it re-copies or resumes copying as the case may be.

EDIT: please use the -H flag in this case as per comments, in order to preserve hard links.

Comment: rsync doesn't maintain hard links on directories. Copying a while TM backup will duplicate a lot of directories

Comment: @patrix - I can confirm this. I've tried it. Directory hard-links are nearly unique to HFS+, and rsync does not understand them.

Comment: -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not get it done faster, but I've found is a way to copy the data properly while preserving the de-duplication (hard links) and permissions. As an added bonus I use this to make a compressed dmg of the final product for archiving.

1. Using Disk Utilities, make a disk image that is larger then your Backups.backupdb directory. I would also suggest that you use sparse bundle disk image for Image Format and Hard disk for Partitions. After this image is mounted, Get info on it and unselect Ignore ownership on this volume.
2. Now turn off Time Machine, and using the finder copy the Backups.backupdb folder to the mounted image. The finder will ask you for super user permissions to copy the data. Get a drink or do something else for a while.
3. When the copy is finished, look to be sure everything is okay and unmount the image. From Disk Utility, select Convert and turn the sparse bundle image into a compressed image. Again, this may take a while.

You should end up with two copies of your Time Machine backup, you can delete the sparse bundle version, and put the dmg in a safe place as an archive in time.

One thing I haven't tried with this is to do a system restore from the dmg, but I suspect that it should work, my goal was more for archiving the time machine incremental changes and keeping the hard link structure.

I have also tried rsync and cp, but they didn't seem to keep the hard link structure which would end up making x times the size, x being the amount of dates you had in the past. This method worked well, but again may not get speed of a block copy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to copy almost full TM 2Gb disk to 1Tb. So, I've written a small script to make it possible. Unfortunately target folders take more space than source folders. In case someone have ideas how it can be solved I'd like to know.

Here's line to gist with the script – https://gist.github.com/tyzhnenko/d17b3cdc7ec6edf4164d788b552c1513

Comment: It can be solved by not using rsync see my answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35183/237

Comment: @mmmmmm I've tried SuperDuper and got two problems in my case. The fist one –  it works only for disks with same size. I can't copy TB archive from a lager disk to smaller. And the second one – SD copies source disk id, to target one. It works for replacement. If you would like to use both disks together TM does strange things – it thinks that disk is hijacked :(

Comment: rsync or any file copy program will duplicate things as they don't understand hard-links so you need something that uses asr or other Apple tools

Comment: @mmmmmm asr just restore. ditto as you said can't save diff copy structure. my script uses prev backup folder to make own hard links. It helps a bit. In my case size of copied backups has ~20% growth

Comment: Does your script hard link directories?

Comment: @mmmmmm hope, I just run rsync with link-dest option. unfortunately rsync doesn't support hard link for directories

Comment: @mmmmmm Isn't that what precisely what the "-H, --hard-links            preserve hard links" flag of rsync is meant to address? https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync Though despite using that flag, I still ran out of space at my destination, so clearly something didn't work how I expected it to 

Comment: @Alexander No That rsync option keeps hard links for FILES which I think all POSIX file systems support. Apple added hard-links for DIRECTORIES that only their file systems support

Answer (score -1):

Apple has an official tutorial for this: “[Time Machine: How to transfer backups from a current backup drive to a new backup drive](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380)”.

The high-level steps from that page:

> 1. Check the format of your new backup drive
> 2. Set permissions on your new backup drive
> 3. Temporarily turn Time Machine off
> 4. Copy your backup data from your original drive to your new drive
> 5. Set Time Machine to use your new drive

This is how the page recommends doing the copying step:

> ### Copy your backup data from your original drive to your new drive
>
> 1. Open a new Finder window. In the Finder sidebar, click the icon of the original backup drive.
> 2. Open a new Finder window. In the Finder sidebar, click the icon of the new backup drive.
> 3. Drag the folder "Backups.backupdb" from the original backup drive to the top level of the new backup drive.
> 4. Enter an administrator name and password, then click OK to start the copying process.
>
> Copying your backup data might take some time to complete, depending on the size of your backup.

Comment: I for one am looking at this question because following that tutorial (which suggests copying the backup folder with Finder) and leaving it running overnight, it ended on some permission issue with about 500/940gb copied. I then did a `sudo rsync` last night, but this morning find `ERROR: out of memory in flist_expand [sender]` and my copy is now ~600gb. I haven't decided what to do next, but suspect most people reading are already aware of the official tutorial.

Comment: @PeterT I have just tried the tuto too and got the same issue as you. I am not sure anyone knew about the tutorial, otherwise someone would have mentioned it here and the outcome following it. Now, people know it is not worth trying.

Comment: Using finder to copy the folder takes an age to build the file list and then fails anyway with not enough disk space so must be miscalculating.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. The original TM volume is 550GB, the new one was 600GB. Still Mojave complained about insufficient space on the volume. I'm using now SuperDuper! in "Backup - all files" mode.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Apple's tutorial **failed** for me, in macOS Mojave 10.14.2.  I tried to copy a 3TB backup archive to an 8TB drive; Finder spent nearly 5 days copying (saying ‘5 seconds left’ for most of that), before giving up and complaining that the drive was full!  And it was — even though it had only copied about 2/3 of the backups.  Clearly, it's not preserving hardlinks but creating fresh copies of each.  So this answer is not currently correct.

Comment: Apple's file copy failed stating some files could not be copied.  This was on Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2). The failure was reported after 36 hours of copying 23 million files.

Answer (score -2):

With hard drives, when you move multiple files from one drive, the reader moves back and forth making a scary clicking noise, and it slows the transfer rate significantly, for example- one file with usb 2.0 moves at 30 mbps on my computer from 2 external harddrives, but 2 files move at 11 mbps. and 3 files move at 6 mbps. etc etc. zip files will move faster than files.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?