# Migrate a Time Machine backup in terminal

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, restore

`/Volumes/Original_Time_Machine` is no longer being backed up to, but contains old backups that I want to keep.

`/Volumes/New_Time_Machine_Archive` is an empty partition

Both of these are on separate physical hard drives.

I was thinking of doing this in the terminal.
Connect both physical hard drives, then:

```
cd /Volumes/Original_Time_Machine
cp -rp * "/Volumes/New_Time_Machine_Archive"
```

Would I be able to restore from this if I copy this way? Or is there another way I should do it?

Comment: What is your goal? Continue using the files for Time Machine backup? Recover data from all snapshots?

Comment: Is this volume being backed up an APFS volume? Of so, I don't think the documentation is quite available to figure your solution out. APFS get localsnapshots, and they are taken by 'tmutil' which was a change from 'diskutil' doing it before. You’ll see the remnants in diskutils output. Those local snapshots are what get backed up in increments. Keep looking though!

Comment: @n1000 Essentially, my goal was to move the backups from one disc to another as I was going to format the hard drive I was *copying from*.

Comment: This worked for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343920/11282

Answer (score 8):

Apple has fixed Finder in macOS 10.13.4 to preserve hard links so my answer is to use Finder to migrate your TM backup. They did not, however, fix `cp`. It still does not preserve hard links and doesn't have an option to do so.

I know the OP requested a way of doing it from the terminal but all my efforts to do so in macOS 10.13.3, where I had given up on Finder because it did not then preserve hard links, failed.

The `rsync` command suggested by [@n1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/45492/n1000) failed after more than 12 hours with out of memory, even though I have 16GB of memory. This is a known problem fixed in rsync v3+. However v3 sets all the user and group ids to 99 and was painfully slow. There were long periods with no disk and no significant CPU activity. I've found `rsync` very slow on other platforms too.

`cpio` did not preserve ownership.

`pax` got strange errors.

I came closest to success with `tar`:

```
cd /Volumes/My\ Passport
sudo bash
tar -cf - -T ~/TMFileList | (cd ../My\ Canvio;tar -xpvSf -)
```

where `~/TMFileList` was created with

```
cd /Volumes/My\ Passport
sudo bash
find -d Backups.backupdb -print > ~/TMFileList
```

[I tried a `tar -c | tar -x` thing first but that was copying some hard links as separate files for reasons related, I guessed, to the order it was seeing the files. Which led to me making the depth-first list.]

However `tar` was taking an impractically long time. I killed it after 3 days. Some of this was because it was extracting files multiple times. The majority of this was, like `rsync`, due to long periods of inactivity for reasons I could not determine. What it managed to complete had correct ownership and hard links were preserved.

So I strongly recommend using Finder. Just make sure you have macOS 10.13.4. Follow the Apple support instructions in the link at the end of [@n1000's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/45492/n1000) answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Apple has fixed Finder"? Can you provide a link to some documentation or an article?

Comment: Prior to 10.13.4, Finder did not preserve hard links when copying. Since TM backups make much use of hard links this meant a Finder created copy would be multiple times the size of the original. In my case a copy of a 500GB backup set to a new 2TB disk failed due to out of space. Apple fixed this in 10.13.4, apparently in response to a bug I filed at bugreporter.apple.com (#36944937). Those bugs are not public so I can't provide a link. They asked me to verify the issue in 10.13.4 suggesting they had fixed it. I did. The copy is now the exact size of the original and hard links are preserved.

Comment: @msc wow, that's amazing... I'll give that a go after updating my os. Thanks for doing that!

Comment: FYI, I just tried using Finder on macOS 10.14.2, and it did not copy hard links properly. The two partitions are an identical type, one larger than the other. Unfortunate, maybe this is a regression in Finder, unclear to me. :-(

Comment: @chmac I just had to do a TM copy in 10.14.2 due to a disk problem. It basically worked. It got to a point where Finder said "5 seconds remaining" at which point the copy was the same size as the original. However "5 seconds remaining" went on for 3 hours until I hit Cancel. During that time it periodically copied very small chunks of data gradually increasing the size of the copy. No idea why. But the copy is okay albeit a few megabyte larger than the original.

Comment: @msc Is it possible that you'd left Time Machine running during the Finder copy? That might explain the failure to finish, and the small final chunks.

Comment: @taryn, it's possible. It was a long time ago.

Comment: @msc I'm just now seeing this exact same behaviour on 10.14.6, with TM definitely not running. Canceling breaks the copy, too, as it isn't complete (although Finder is saying 0 files left). So, for me too, using Finder (as recommended by Apple) is not a viable option. I'm not yet sure what is a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested to the answers and comments in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/138587/how-to-copy-symbolic-links#comment813470_138588), the `-p` option will not work on a Mac. I tested `-rp` and it will convert symbolic links to real files. That means when you use this your Time Machine backup will become significantly larger. Time Machine creates symbolic links for redundant files and therefore avoids copying duplicate files between the snapshots.

Hence, use

```
cp -a
```

to preserve the symbolic links. This will be necessary if you plan on continuing to use the data for Time Machine backups. Alternatively, you could also use `rsync` using the `-K` option to preserve symlinks, e.g.:

```
rsync -ahvrK
```

[This Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380) describes the procedure for migrating a backup from one drive to another (using Finder).

Comment: My goal is to transfer this data and have OS X recognize the drive I move it to as a time machine backup and not just a regular partition

Comment: @KolobCanyon OK, I see. The title suggests it more or less. I suggest you edit your question to make it more obvious. My answer should do what you want.

Comment: The man for `-a    Same as -pPR options. Preserves structure and attributes of
           files but not directory structure.` ... Don't I want to preserve directory structure?

Comment: TimeMachine uses hard links not symbolic links.

Comment: And `man cp` on macOS reveals that `cp` copies hard links as separate files thus enlarging backups.

Comment: `rysnc` *might* work provided your backup is not large. For me after many, many hours of "Building file list..." it filled up my 16GB of memory and quit. With this and the problem noted in my earlier comments, I have to down-vote this answer.

Comment: @msc I appreciate the heads-up. I cannot verify your comments right now. Make sure to provide an alternative answer if you find a better way.

Comment: The proper rsync option to preserve hard links is -H / --hard-links, though -K seems to be useful, too. I can't say however if this is enough to produce a working time machine backup copy (mine is still copying).

Comment: This answer is misleading and in my opinion should at least be downvoted. Copying symbolic links is not the issue with TimeMachine backups.