# How to copy Time Machine directory when rsync can see files but ls can't?

Tags: time-machine, rsync, disk-image

I recently used GNU `ddrescue` to save a 6TB drive that was having troubles. When I would try to mount the drive, `fsck_hfs` determined it couldn't be fixed (it was trying to rebuild the catalog b-tree, but then said the disk was full and it couldn't write it). The drive would then mount read-only, and I found that I would get an `input-output error` if I tried to `ls` into my Time Machine backup directory. After trying many things that didn't work, I decided to just `ddrescue` it to a 6TB .dmg, which did work with no bad sectors.

So, now I have a 6TB .dmg image of the drive, and I find that it has the same issues: `fsck_hfs` thinks it cannot be fixed, and it gives `input/output error` when trying to `ls` into the Time Machine directory. I subsequently formatted the external drive, and it seems to be fine, so I *think* it was never a hardware issue.

I found out that although `ls` doesn't like the Time Machine directory, `rsync` seems fine with it. When I try to sync the directory to a new disk with `rsync -avhHW --progress <image> <dest>`, the output lists all the files I expect, and I can successfully see them appearing on the destination. However, this doesn't seem to work for copying a Time Machine directory, because the size balloons on the destination. `rsync` used to have `--hfs-compression` and `--protect-decmpfs` options, but they seem to be broken in v3.1.3, and as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1055656/time-machine-size-explodes-when-copied-to-new-drive) those may not be enough anyway. Indeed, I find that I've filled a 6TB destination before even making it through half of the directories in the 6TB image.

I am trying to copy the files through Finder now, but it is (understandably) spending ages just preparing. I liked the idea of using `rsync` not only because it could actually see the files, but because it is ok if interrupted.

So, does anyone know why `rsync` can see these files when `ls` can't? Is there any way I can copy them over in a way that is safe to be interrupted but doesn't ruin the hfs+ compression or mess up the hard links (or hard-linked directories, which is what [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1055656/time-machine-size-explodes-when-copied-to-new-drive) claims is the problem with `rsync` even when it did have the old options)?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since Time Machine *has* to be on HFS+ have you tried using a third party disk repair utility? My favorite was Diskwarrior but there are others.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and congrats on the clear wording and details in your question. I don't have a good answer for you, but after reading one of the other posts you referenced I started wondering if rsync not supporting hard linked directories was a bug that was being tracked. That led me to https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7670 which references differences in behaviour where `rsync` and Apple's `ditto` succeeds. So maybe `ditto` would be useful for you to try here?

Comment: @SteveChambers I hadn't tried Diskwarrior because it was paid, although I have heard good things. All I have remaining now is the .dmg; the original disk has been formatted. Can utilities like Diskwarrior repair these?

Comment: @woolfie I may have stumbled on that same thread, because I remember seeing something about `ditto`. I haven't tried it yet, I will do that next! Thank you.

Comment: Another thought I had tried earlier was to just expand the .dmg so that `fsck_hfs` could repair it, since it claimed the issue was a disk full error. Alas, the .dmg created by `ddrescue` cannot be expanded, so says `hdiutil resize -limits`. My knowledge of these things is limited, but if there were another way to expand the size of the disk image, it's another thing I would want to try.

Comment: @woolfie From [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35149/is-there-a-faster-way-to-copy-time-machine-files-from-one-disk-to-another) it looks like maybe ditto will also cause the destination to blow up, as it doesn't handle directory hard links.

Comment: I *believe* DW will fix a R/W disk image. Make a copy though, just in case. And DW Tech Support is pretty responsive...